# parameterized queries in Excel with SQLite ODBC

Tags: excel, vba, sqlite, odbc

I'm using the [SQLite ODBC Driver](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/) v0.9993 in Excel 2016 (win10). The main impetus for using an external source is that I have too much data for Excel to sanely manage, so it will be pulled based on user-selected criteria. Because of this, I'd like to use parameterized queries based on the contents of well-defined worksheet cells.

I'm trying two methods:

1. Straight VBA, where I do something like this (rough code):

   ```
   Sub UpdateTables()
       Dim ws as Worksheet
       Dim adoCN As ADODB.Connection
       Dim adoCmd As ADODB.Command
       Dim adoRS As ADODB.Recordset
       Dim sDB as String
       Dim rCell as Range
       Set adoCN = New ADODB.Connection
       Set adoRS = New ADODB.Recordset
       ' ws is set to correct worksheet
       ' ...
       ' define sDB from worksheet cell
       With adoCN
           .Open "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=True;" _
               & "Driver={SQLite3 ODBC Driver};" _
               & "Database=" & sDB & ";" _
               & "DSN=SQLite3 Datasource;LongNames=true;fksupport=true", "", "" '
       End With
       Set adoCmd = New ADODB.Command
       adoCmd.ActiveConnection = adoCN
       ' rCell points to cell containing query parameter
       Set adoParam = adoCmd.CreateParameter(, adVarChar, adParamInput, _
           Len(rCell.value), rCell.value)
       adoCmd.Parameters.Append adoParam
       adoCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE X = ?"
       adoRS.Open Source:=adoCmd, CursorType:=adOpenKeyset
       With ws.ListObjects(1).QueryTable
           Set .RecordSet = adoRS
           .Refresh ' errors with "Error 1004: invalid accessor flag"
       End With
   End Sub
   ```

   (Code has been simplified, generally I include sanity checks.)
2. GUI-based in Excel, with *New Query* > *From Other Sources* > *From ODBC*, set DSN to "SQLite3 Datasource", and enter in the Connection string used above.

   Unfortunately, the "Parameters" button (*Connections* > *select query* > *Properties* > *Definition* tab) is grayed out.

I think I prefer the second solution, but neither is working at the moment.

Comment: Why don't you use the first method and change the command to `adoCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE X = " & Worksheets(1).Range("RangeForParameter").Value2`? That should work. Why do you say that the first isn't working? What do you mean by that?

Comment: Primarily because that's not parameterization. Though I think it's unlikely that a user will enter into a cell `5;DROP TABLE users;`, I also believe it will be faster and more sustainable in the long haul.

Comment: I say the first method isn't working because it errs with "Error 1004: invalid accessor flag". It's a vague error with no clear indication of a remedy.

Comment: `Set adoParam = adoCmd.CreateParameter(, adVarChar, adParamInput, _
        Len(rCell.value), rCell.value` is missing a closing paren `)`

Comment: Thanks ... that wasn't causing my problem (IDE would be clear about that mistake), but I obviously made a copy/paste mistake.

Comment: Curious, why chose SQLlite when Excel if using PC already has an installed SQL engine called Jet/ACE a pre-built Windows .dll and the default engine of MS Access, a file-level RDMS like SQLlite which PC users can use without full Access exe GUI program!

Comment: Good question. The accdb format isn't supported by the tools generating the database, and the MDB file is literally over 10x the size of the sqlite3 file. I'll ask on other channels on getting accdb to work, hoping that it is much better at file size than MDB.

Comment: Update: found one method for using accdb files, and though I have not verified all the data yet, it's only 25% larger than sqlite3, so the size may be acceptable for the interface cleanliness. Thanks for the suggestion, @Parfait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than [opening recordset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) via an ADO connection, you need to execute the command from [ADO command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object. This an often discussed topic of *recordset .execute vs .open*. Of course, be sure to add error handling to capture relevant errors/exceptions.

```
Sub UpdateTables()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    Dim ws as Worksheet
    Dim adoCN As New ADODB.Connection, adoRS As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim adoCmd As New ADODB.Command    
    Dim sDB as String
    Dim rCell as Range

    'Set ws = ... '
    'sDB = ... '

    ' DATABASE CONNECTION '   
    adoCN.Open "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=True;" _
                  & "Driver={SQLite3 ODBC Driver};" _
                  & "Database=" & sDB & ";" _
                  & "DSN=SQLite3 Datasource;LongNames=true;fksupport=true", "", "" 

    ' ADO COMMAND '
    With adoCmd
        .ActiveConnection = adoCN
        .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE X = ?"
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adVarChar, adParamInput, _
                                            Len(rCell.value), rCell.value)
    End With

    ' EXECUTE RECORDSET '
    Set adoRS = adoCmd.Execute

    ' DEFINE QUERYTABLE '
    With ws.ListObjects(1).QueryTable
        Set .RecordSet = adoRS
        .Refresh
    End With

    ' CLOSE AND FREE RESOURCES '
    adoRS.Close: adoCN.Close
    Set adoRS = Nothing: Set adoCmd = Nothing: Set adoCN = Nothing    
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Set adoRS = Nothing: Set adCmd = Nothing: Set adCN = Nothing    
    Exit Sub    
End Sub
```

Comment: At one point I was having problems that switching to `adOpenStatic` (for `Recordset.Open`) solved, and I couldn't figure out how to specify that option with `.Execute`. I'll give this a try again, thanks for the help!

Comment: Indeed. Just tested on a MySQL connection. Also please check your connection string as you currently have Provider, Driver, and DSN together when it should be one of the three with data source (i.e., file) and any options (ODBC/DSNs can be checked in odbcad32.exe).

Comment: I thought that, too, but during troubleshooting (lots of that going on) I grabbed the connection string excel was using internally. Overkill, perhaps, but once I got it working, reducing it became a low priority.